# How to divide Dataframes to list of Dataframes based on values in columns, but without changing any structures

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I saw a few similar question but I didn't find a case like this. It is my first time using pandas DataFrame.

I have DataFrame:

```
    A    B    C
0   0    1    2
1   0    1    3
2   0    2    4
3   1    1    4
4   1    1    3
```

and i would like to divide this Data Frame into list of DataFrames based on columns A and B, so I would like to have  a 3 three DataFrames in result, like this:

1. ```
       A    B    C
   0   0    1    2
   1   0    1    3
   ```

2.

```
    A    B    C
2   0    2    4
```

3.

```
    A    B    C
3   1    1    4
4   1    1    3
```

Could you write me how to do it please(with explanation)?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what's the logic for splitting your dataframe like that?

Comment: Use `d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(['A','B'])))`

Comment: Please check solution and if still some problem, let me know.

Comment: thx, this is what i was looking for